# What is "X-Require-Whisk-Auth" (IBM Cloud Functions) in IBM Cloud Code Engine functions?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have some [IBM Cloud Functions secured web actions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-actions_web#actions_web_secure) that I want to migrate to [IBM Cloud Code Engine functions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-fun-work). The web action is using "X-Require-Whisk-Auth". What would be the equivalent in Code Engine? How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `__ce_headers` in the parameters passed to your Code Engine function, you have access to all headers and their values which were part of the functions request. This includes the "Authorization" header (if used) or "X-Require-Whisk-Auth" if simulating Cloud Functions behavior.

The following Python code snippet shows how to obtain the value for that header.

```
def main(params):
    auth=""
    # check for "X-Require-Whisk-Auth" header
    if "X-Require-Whisk-Auth" in params["__ce_headers"]:
        auth=params["__ce_headers"]["X-Require-Whisk-Auth"]
        # perform next steps
```

Comment: Related blog post on using the regular Authentication header with Code Engine functions: https://blog.4loeser.net/2024/03/ibm-cloud-code-engine-function-security.html